# How can I load a external QML file in Qt Quick?

Tags: qt, qml

Ok like if I'm trying to make something like a menu for a simple game. How can I make it so that when the start button is clicked it loads a different QML file?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Qt.createComponent()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-qt.html#createComponent-method) or [Loader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-loader.html). For example:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
  MyButton {
    onClicked: loader.source = "MyGameFile.qml"
  }
  Loader {
    id: loader
    anchors.fill: parent
  }
}
```

Comment: if i have to download qml file from server, how can i specify here?